# What's the "deselect all" hotkey in Blender 2.8x?

Tags: customization, shortcut

Recently I've been trying to transition from an earlier version of Blender to 2.82. The UI is easy enough to figure out but the thing that really gets me is the bind to deselect all. In earlier versions, I could press <kbd>A</kbd> to select and deselect all but now I have to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to deselect which really bothers me. If possible, I would like this to work in both *Object* and *Edit* mode.

I've tried going into preferences and changing the (de)select binds from <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to <kbd>A</kbd> but it hasn't worked.

In essence, I want the keymapping to be the same as in earlier versions of blender; <kbd>A</kbd> to select and deselect all.

Comment: I am not happy happy about the situation either.⌨

Comment: Nah Alt is great and consistent with many other uses.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118778/2-8-select-and-deselect-like-in-2-79 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130641/how-can-i-get-single-a-to-deslect-in-2-8

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Press <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> ... that is a double <kbd>A</kbd>.
<kbd>A</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> will deselect all.

Comment: I guess that works. It's not ideal but I'll take it over having to press Alt. Thanks.

Comment: @ZaneD I hated it at first but I use the command so often it felt natural after a few days

Answer (score 8):

The old behaviour is still available in Blender 2.82. Go to the Keymap section of Preferences, and in the first panel (titled ‘Preferences’) tick the ‘Select All Toggles’ option.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had no idea it can be switched on like that :).